# Number of electrons in a 2D box for degenerate energy levels

Tags: quantum-chemistry

As we know that the energy of a 2-D box depends on two quantum numbers say $n$ and $m$ so
$$
{E \propto n^2 +m^2}
$$
Now if we say that $n=1$ and $m=1$ so only one energy level is there and 2 electrons of different spin can be accommodated

if we take $n=1$ , $m=2$ or $n=2$ , $m=1$ , the energy level will be the same for these quantum numbers, but the wavefunctions will be different, as well as the probability distribution functions.

So my question is : Can we only  2 electrons in this energy level, or 4 electrons considering that there are two different wavefunctions for this energy level ?

Comment: This suits more to Physics SE, as there are not even atoms or ions to say there is some relation to quantum chemistry. // Aside of that, try to reconsider the question readability and eventually reformulate it.

Comment: There are always two energy levels, which is easier to see if the box is not square so you could look at the full formula. The levels are accidentally degenerate for the cases you list only because the box is square .

Comment: Ever heard of Pythagoras?